# What's the residue of $xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$ in $x=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

I've been trying to get the residue of $xe^{\frac{1}{x}}$ in $x = 0$. I know the result is 1/2 but I don't know how to get to that result. The most I've done is use L'Hôpital and got $\frac{1}{\frac {e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{x^2}}$. From here I don't know where to go. Any help?

Comment: try expanding the exponential in a Taylor series and pick off the 1/x term

Comment: Why the 1/x term @DinosaurEgg ? Sorry but I'm starting with residues. Is it because is the $a_{-1}$ term?

Comment: If $f(z)$ is analytic and non-zero and $a$ is inside the contour, then $\frac {1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac {f(z)}{z-a} \ dz = f(a)$ and $n>1 \implies \frac {1}{2\pi i}\oint \frac {f(z)}{(z-a)^n} \ dz = 0 $ i.e. the residues are coefficients of the $\frac {1}{z-a}$ terms in the Laurent expansion

Comment: For a pole of order $n$ you can use $$\text{Res}(f,c)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to c}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z-c)^nf(z),$$ but I nearly always find resorting to Taylor series expansion easier to do by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $e^x= \sum_{n\geqslant 0} x^n/(n!) \Rightarrow e^{(1/x)} = \sum_{n\geqslant 0} 1/(x^n \cdot n!)$.

Therefore, $x e^\left({1/x}\right) = \sum_{n\geqslant 0} 1/(x^{n-1} \cdot n!)$. Then, residuo is $a_{-1} = 1/2! = 1/2$